# Python suffix Generator

Tags: python, list

The following Python code should generate all possible suffixes. So on input [1, 2, 3], the following should be generated: `[[], [3], [2, 3], [1,2,3]]`

```
def suffixes(lst):
    return [lst [t:len(lst)+1-t] for t in range ( len(lst)+1, 0 , -1)]

print suffixes ([1, 2])
```

I keep getting the following output:

```
[ [], [], [2] ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner way to do it would probably be to do this:

```
return [lst[t:] for t in range(len(lst), -1, -1)]
```

The `range` counts `t` backwards from the end of the list to the beginning, taking suffixes as you go on.

The reason your solution doesn't work is because of the `len(lst+1)`, which you probably intended to be `len(lst)+1`.

Also, you start your `range` at `len(lst) + 1`, so you get `[]` twice, because the suffix starting after the end of the list is the same as the suffix starting at the end of the list.

You also end your `range` at `0`. Because `range` is exclusive on the second argument, you never get the whole list as one of your suffixes. You need to end the `range` at `-1` to include `t=0` in the list comprehension.

Comment: It's not really cleaner, just gives the result in reverse order.

Comment: The question asked for the result in the order `[[], [3], [2, 3], [1,2,3]]`, which is what my solution does.

Comment: Didn't say it wasn't correct. I argued agasint it being "cleaner".

Comment: The reason I said it was cleaner was mostly the lack of a second argument on the sublist operator `lst[t:]`.

Comment: The questioner's updated second argument `len(lst)+1-t` is flagrantly wrong anyway.